# AngularJS - Failed to instantiate module when passing parameters in url

Tags: angularjs, url, express, url-parameters

I have the following URL defined in my routes.js file:

```
app.get('/animal/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendfile('./public/views/animal.html')
});
```

This is `app.js`:

```
var app = angular.module('adote', ['ngCookies', 'ngResource', 'ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'flow', 'ngTagsInput', 'ngSanitize', 'mgcrea.ngStrap'])

  app.config(function($locationProvider, $routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    })
```

This is the link for index.html (there's not much here): https://gist.github.com/larissaleite/6280ca1bcd9886e7b253

This is where I do all the configuration on my application:

```
app.use(cookieParser('appsecret'));

app.use(session({ secret: 'appsecret', saveUninitialized: true, cookie: { secure: true, maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000) } }));

// configuration ===============================================================
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/Routing');

// connect to mongoDB database
mongoose.connection.once('connected', function(error){
    if (error) {
        console.log("Error: " + error);
    } else {
        console.log("Connected to the database");
    }
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));         // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());

require('./app/routes.js')(app, passport);
```

This is routes.js complete:

```
var Animal = require('./models/animal');
var User = require('./models/user');

module.exports = function(app, passport) {

    require('../config/passport')(passport); // pass passport for configuration

    app.get('/home', function(req, res, next) {
        console.log(req.isAuthenticated());
        res.sendfile('./public/views/home.html');
    });

    app.get('/cadastro', function(req, res, next) {
        res.sendfile('./public/views/cadastro.html');
    });

    app.get('/animal/:id', function(req, res, next) {
        res.sendfile('./public/views/animal.html')
    });

    app.get('/api/animals', function(req, res, next) {
        console.log("GET - api/animals");

        Animal.find({}, function(err, animals) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("erro");
                res.send(err);
            }
            if (!animals.length) {
                res.send("not found");
            } else {
                res.json(animals);
            }
        });
    });

    app.get('/api/animal/:id', function(req, res, next) {
        //changed from query to params after removing angularjs routing
        console.log("GET - api/animal/id = "+req.params.id);

        Animal.findById(req.params.id, function(err, animal) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("erro");
                res.send(err);
            } else {
                res.json(animal);
            }
        });
    });

    app.post('/api/animal', function(req, res, next) {
        console.log("POST - api/animal");

        console.log(req.body.tags);
        //console.log(req.body.localizacoes);

        var animal = new Animal({
            nome: req.body.nome,
            tipo: req.body.tipo,
            tags: req.body.tags,
            localizacoes: req.body.localizacoes,
            descricao: req.body.descricao,
            usuario_nome: "Maria Joaquina",
            eventos: req.body.eventos
        });

        animal.save(function(err) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.send("success");
        }); 
    });

    // =====================================
    // FACEBOOK ROUTES =====================
    // =====================================
    // route for facebook authentication and login
    app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope : 'email' }));

    // handle the callback after facebook has authenticated the user
    app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
        passport.authenticate('facebook', {
            successRedirect : '/home',
            failureRedirect : '/login'
        }));

    // route for logging out
    app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
        console.log("logout");
        req.session.regenerate(function(){
            req.logout();
            res.redirect('/login');
        });
    });

    app.get('*', function(req, res) {
        res.sendfile('./public/index.html');
    });

}
```

I also have a controller called `AnimalCtrl`, which makes a GET request to my Express API:

```
$http({url: '/api/animal/:id', method: 'GET', params : { id: $routeParams.id } })
  .success(function(response) {
    ...
  }).error(function(response){
     console.log("erro "+response);
  });
```

However, I get the following error when I type in the url `http://localhost:8080/animal/5429d6fa20348a6178cb1890`

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < app.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < animal.js:1
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module adote due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'adote' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or    forgot to load it. 
If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

What is a bit strange that I noticed that the id 5429d6fa20348a6178cb1890 is interpreted as if it was a file
[image]

This is my complete file structure:

[image]

Can someone help me with this?

Thank you!

Comment: The first 2 errors are telling you that you have a syntax error in your javascript code.  The AngularJs errors are because it couldn't find the `adote` module that you defined -- because the file with the code wasn't loaded because of the syntax error.  In short, fix your syntax errors.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Do you mean javascript error in the Controller? The only thing the Controller has is the code I posted above. I've even tried to comment it but I got the same problem. I use the same structure and the module is instantiated just fine in other pages of my application. How does it relate to the parameter I have in the URL?

Comment: Is your issue solved? If not, I might help. I believe the error lies in yoyr express routing and not in angular. Coukd you share your express routing config? The unexpected character '<' probably comes from your index.html file that express is serving because it cannot find the correct route. Best regards

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @apairet! Not solved yet :( I edited the question and included my routes.js file. If you need anything else, let me know.

Comment: Please also post your app.js file. Note it is very uncommon to serve your static files from your route.js file. You could replace your res.sendfile(xyz.html) by defining your 'views' directory: app.set('views', config.root + '/views');

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code on github (https://github.com/larissaleite/Routing), here is an updated answer.
The issue is in your index.html file, replace:

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

by (see the leading `/`)

```
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

Do not forget to add all your controllers to your index.html:

```
<script src="/js/controllers/animal.js"></script>
<script src="/js/controllers/home.js"></script>
<script src="/js/controllers/cadastro.js"></script>
```

Your index.html 'asks' for javascript files but receives your index.html because your server cannot 'resolve' the path your provide in your index.html. Using Chrome Dev Tools, if you look at the response from the server when asked for js/apps.js you should see it receives index.html
It is due to these lines:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./public/index.html');
});
```

Define a view folder (see http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.set)

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/public/views');
```

and remove these lines from your route.js:

```
app.get('/home', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.isAuthenticated());
    res.sendfile('./public/views/home.html');
});

app.get('/cadastro', function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendfile('./public/views/cadastro.html');
});

app.get('/animal/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendfile('./public/views/animal.html')
});
```

Some other advices:

1. Add a .gitignore file. You do not have to track node_modules and bower_components folders
2. I would recommend you to use a router for your frontend app: see ngRoute or uiRouter

Comment: Thanks for you answer, @apairet! I've just edited the question. If you need more info, let me know

Comment: I didn't manage to get it to work like that. Should I remove ALL routes that returns HTML files? Because I tried removing all of them and also just leaving the default one ('*'), but neither of them worked. Maybe I am missing something

Comment: Ok, this is what a thought. I will update the answer tonight. Just to make sure, what version of express do you use? 3 or 4? Could you show more of your index.html? What other scripts do you load? I only see app.js but nithing about your controller. Thx

Comment: Express 4. I load a different controller for each one of the htmls files. index.html just has a button to Log in with Facebook, that's why there are no controllers attached. As for the other pages, all of them see app.js and its respective controller

Comment: @LarissaLeite I updated the answer. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @apairet. __dirname is showing the correct path. I tried this solution and I keep being redirected to index.html, no matter which view I type in (I tried /cadastro, without parameters, and also /animal/:id)

Comment: I saw there exists a github repo for your code. If you push your problematic code to it,Iwill pull it and have a look. We are both loosing time due to ping-pong ;-)

Comment: Yeah, good idea. I've just pushed this code to a new repo. Sorry the code is a bit messy https://github.com/larissaleite/Routing

Comment: Thanks! I still keep being redirected to index.html. I was using AngularJS routing (as you might've seen in my other repo). Although I didn't have any problems with the url parameters, I was having CORS issues when trying to authenticate with facebook. That's why I decided to try a different approach. Anyway, I updated the code on GitHub if you wanna take a look again

Comment: @LarissaLeite please accept the answer as it fixes the issue you described: error in the console and angular module initiation problems. I would consider following this guide: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07 and if you still have problems, open a new question. regards

Comment: Unfortunately, my issue isn't solved (before I was able to access other pages/views that didn't require parameters)... I don't have any problems with Angular routing, but CORS issues prevented me from moving forward with that approach. I really appreciate you help, thank you.